# Why can't the IT industry deliver large, faultless projects quickly as in other industries?

Tags: project-management, development-process, time-management, industry

After watching National Geographic's [MegaStructures series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MegaStructures), I was surprised how fast large projects are completed. Once the preliminary work (design, specifications, etc.) is done on paper, **the realization itself of huge projects takes just a few years or sometimes a few months**.

For example, [Airbus A380](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A380) ["formally launched on Dec. 19, 2000", and "in the Early March, 2005"](http://borislw.hubpages.com/hub/Project-Schedule-The-making-of-Airbus-A380), the aircraft was already tested. The same goes for huge oil tankers, skyscrapers, etc.

Comparing this to the delays in the software industry, I can't help wondering why most IT projects are so slow, or more precisely, why they cannot be as fast and faultless, at the same scale, given enough people?

---

Projects such as the Airbus A380 present both:

- Major unforeseen risks: while this is not the first aircraft built, it still pushes the limits of the technology and things which worked well for smaller airliners may not work for the larger one due to physical constraints; in the same way, new technologies are used which were not used before, because for example they were not available in 1969 when the Boeing 747 was certified.
- Risks related to human resources and management in general: people quitting in the middle of the project, inability to reach a person because she's on vacation, ordinary human errors, etc.

With those risks, **people still achieve projects like those large airliners in a very short period of time**, and despite the delivery delays, those projects are still hugely successful and of a high quality.

When it comes to software development, the projects are hardly as large and complicated as an airliner (both technically and in terms of management), and have slightly less unforeseen risks from the real world.

Still, **most IT projects are slow and late**, and adding more developers to the project is not a solution (going from a team of ten developers to two thousand will sometimes make it possible to deliver the project faster, sometimes not, and sometimes will only harm the project and increase the risk of not finishing it at all).

Those which are still delivered may often **contain a lot of bugs, requiring consecutive service packs and regular updates** (imagine "installing updates" on every Airbus A380 twice a week to patch the bugs in the original product to prevent the aircraft from crashing).

How can such differences be explained? Is it due exclusively to the fact that the software development industry is too young to be able to manage thousands of people on a single project in order to deliver large scale, nearly faultless products very fast?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm tempted to say the quality of the average worker in the software industry is less skilled and qualified than, say, civil engineering where every engineer has completed a rigorous and intensive degree and likely gained his charter too. Furthermore, the complexity space of large software (eg. an OS, MS Office) is probably much greater even than an aeroplane. Certainly many more places to fail! And a final important point: most software more or less works, even if was poorly written and highly buggy...certainly the cost of failure is normally much less than an aeroplane!

Comment: Any recent mode of transport is full of software, if you're interested in the software quality of aerospace systems then have a look at the DO-178B and DO-178C certifications

Comment: Find someone who actually works in any of those other industries (but not in PR) and ask them about "large faultless projects". I can virtually guarantee that you'll earn pained laughter.

Comment: Primary problem is that every new project usually have new, untested things to solve.

Comment: The realisation of a software project takes seconds or minutes; it's what happens when you click "compile" in your IDE.  On the other hand, *programming is design*.  How long did it take to design the A380?

Comment: That TV program is a hype. They only telecast successful projects. Any channel will make programs for viewers attention.

Comment: That's two successful projects picked from the aviation industry and compared to all the unsuccessful projects from the software industry, without even giving specific examples.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - I don't disagree with your comment, however, it does raise the interesting follow on question of why then, does software development concern itself so much with notions of reuse (components, cohesive classes, OOP etc.) if we essentially have to solve different, new and untested problems each time?

Comment: @CraigTP a guess would be that the world changes fast enough for the basic premises to settle.  If you keep writing DOS programs - which Windows will run - you will provide suboptimal solutions in todays world.

Comment: "Computer programs are the most complex things that humans make." - Douglas Crockford

Comment: Software development exists since.. about 30 years? Maybe 40. Engineering has done virtually ever since! A lot of expierence could be gathered through all the time.

Comment: Why are you surprised? Engineers in general have several millennia head start on software engineers.

Comment: I read somewhere saying that software engineers often underestimate the time required to complete a project. The delays you experienced may simply be the fact that the people set un-reasonable deadlines when in fact it took just as long. Just a theory, not confirmed fact by any means.

Comment: A seasoned PM once told me that in a factory/assembly line like setting, each person/team at every phase has a different expertise. They can't necessarily change something there and then and must be 'escalated back up'. Software - almost everyone on the team can spend sometime, understand code they haven't written and change without necessary regard to downstream repercussions. Not so with other industries

Comment: A quick review would have convinced you that the A380 is certainly not the success you think. Faultless? As recent as 2010 it had a major recall because of a major fault in the Rolls Royce engines.

Comment: Other industries like what?  The construction industry?  Hahahahahaha...

Comment: I seriously doubt the basic premise of this question can be proved.

Comment: Go over to YouTube and search for episodes and clips of the "Seconds From Disaster" series. All isn't perfect in other industries.

Comment: If human got a Airbus, human is happy with it. If human got a patient journal system, it's wrong implemented. I feel it also a result of consumers nature. Differently touched "the canine is to low to roof", engineers say "go and sit". A softwareengineer "of, your probably right, we fix?"

Comment: Ironic that you should pick the A380 as an example of a successful, on time project. The A380 was two years late entering service due to wiring issues, and now all aircraft need to be re-worked to fix cracks in the wings. It's beginning to sound exactly like your typical IT project!

Comment: @Gavin Coates: quoting from my question: "With those risks, people still achieve projects like those large airliners in a very short period of time, and **despite the delivery delays**, those projects are [...]".

Comment: It's easy, just *redefine* success to be the same level in all situations. In the airplane, when your tray table isn't exactly well aligned, you don't bother to complain. If an icon isn't exactly aligned in your software, you'll make much more noise and complaining about it, and so on...

Comment: I downvoted due to the begged question: anyone who's ever lived in an area with major civil works projects or followed the news on projects like the ones you mentioned has reason to question whether they're that much different. A better question would compare some large projects which did and did not procede efficiently to compare the approaches - there's a potentially interesting discussion about strategies for managing complexity.

Comment: The formal launch was in 2000, but the article said development started in 1994. That's 11 years. Imagine writing and testing code for 11 years before shipping.

Comment: 'imagine "installing updates" on every Airbus A380 twice per week...' Imagine enemy robots constantly probing the plane for vulnerabilities while untrained pilots push buttons at random. I bet you'd need regular patches.

Comment: @MainMa - The A380 project was far from developed in a "very short period of time". Officially offered for sale in Dec. 2000, and entered service in Oct 2007. That's 7 years in development. Initial studies began in 1988 before it was even decided it was feasible to do, with the project first announced in 1990. I'm a big fan of the A380, but it certainly isn't a project designed in a short period of time, or a good example of a successful project (in terms of being on time and on budget).

Comment: Paradoxically, because too many people in the IT industry don't know the answer to this question. Neither ask it.

Comment: This article is a better answer than most of the comments posted so far: http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/building-quickbooks-how-intuit-manages-1/240003694

Comment: Management can decide to release software that fails key tests.  But you can't release an air plane that fails physics.

Comment: You talk that it's a given that projects that aren't software related are always more successful.  That isn't necessarially true.  Both the A380 and the Dreamliner had delays and cost overruns, and the F35 program is currently looking like a serious screwup, especially the B variant.  Structural and mechanical engineering disciplines are more mature than those for software, that's certainly a factor, but there are plenty of projects that didn't go well that went nowhere near software.

Comment: Actually, in IT industry there is too much change in small amount of time. This change doesn't allow anyone to master a specific topic fully. For example, if you master Silverlight, you will be told that this is not going to last long, its already dead or it will be superseded by say HTML5 or whatever. So, we should make the stable and promote innovation, rather than killing each others technologies. Also, IT is still is newer than say Automobile industry.

Comment: This is a great answer for this kind of comparison: http://www.stevestreeting.com/2011/06/16/why-software-engineering-is-a-misnomer/

Comment: I love the answer Dijkstra gave more than thirty years ago: [To the economic question "Why is software so expensive?" the equally economic answer could be "Because it is tried with cheap labour."](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD06xx/EWD648.html)

Comment: The reason those construction projects can be designed and built much faster is due to the quality of the software systems that allow the design to be modelled and tested. Weaknesses and design faults are likely to be caught during a simulation. It's unfortunate that the software industry still hasn't implemented these ideas with unit testing to a great degree

Comment: see also: [Does software reuse preclude process repeatability](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/204807/31260)

Comment: Large airliners are generally more reliable than software? Really? Which one usually needs more maintenance?

Comment: Well Airbus A380 was not all about hardware? Software was also involved. :)

Comment: it is just because software building has no strict 'coding' process to follow and has no way of 99.99996% (6 sigma) to be tested like factory, it's more like implementation of human thoughts than a real stuff. and human is just human.

Comment: agreed the premise of the question (that big projects are less problematic outside of software business) is highly questionable & arguably quite false. this question relates to human nature and is nearly anthropological/ cultural. in a word ***politics/ bureacracy*** which is common/ intrinsic/ inescapable to all large human projects and even smaller ones. another basic recent case study is the [boeing dreamliner](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travelnews/10207415/Boeing-787-Dreamliner-a-timeline-of-problems.html) which you conspicuously dont mention and is now world famous for its delays.

Comment: The answer is due to the complexity, number of details, and heterogenous nature of IT projects (the project must satisfy many criteria, handle many different scenarios,) and the fact that many IT projects are built from scratch rather than using well-developed code that's already in existence. Every time you build a new airplane, you're not re-inventing the wheel. And the software that runs on airplanes only has to do a limited set of very specific, predictable things, unlike IT services which are trying to satisfy a wide variety of things many of which are not known in advance.

Comment: It took decades of hard lessons costing lots of lives to get aerospace where it is. Early on american rockets were routinely blowing up on the launch pad. And I think of the 3 Apollo I astronauts burning alive. These tragedies forced us to learn what it meant to design and build true quality.  Challenger and Endeavor loses taught us - twice - the problems of organization culture and management reality distortion. Software just hasn't killed as many people - yet.  Oh - NASA's software bug tolerance is about 1 in 10^6. No software startup would ever implement their process.

Comment: This question is based on a flawed premise: the A380 was delivered years late, was billions of dollars over budget, and had flaws that had to be corrected post-production.  We can find similar issues with bridge, skyscraper, highway, railway, etc. construction, too.

Comment: https://youtu.be/G2X_7ojZwtU Cynefin. Software (complex, some pieces complicated) due to its cognitive and creative aspects is not manufacturing (complicated, sometimes simple).

Comment: @radarbob: "Challenger and Endeavor loses" - Challenger and Columbia were lost. The Endeavour is fine and resting in a museum, according to Wikipedia.

Comment: Oops. Challenger and *Columbia*. My apologies. I don't mean for such a mistake to imply a casual attitude.

Comment: Basically, we are not an industry as such.

Answer (score 364, accepted):

[Ed Yourdon's *Death March*](http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/bookshop/detail.asp?item=100000000043794) touches upon a number of these meta type questions.

In general, the software industry lacks a lot of the following, which gets in the way of large projects.

- Standardization and work item breakdown.

  - This has certainly gotten better, but the design constructs still aren't there to break out a big system. In some ways, software can't even agree on what's *needed* for a given project, much less being able to break things down into components.
  - Aerospace, building construction, auto, etc.. all have very component-driven architectures with reasonably tight interfaces to allow fully parallel development. Software still allows too much bleed through in the corresponding areas.
- A large body of successful, similar projects. The A380 *wasn't* the first big airplane that [Airbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus) built. There are a lot of large software applications out there, but many of them have suffered dramatically in some aspect or the other and wouldn't come close to being called "successful."
- A large body of designers and builders who have worked on a number of similar and successful projects. Related to the successful project issue, not having the human talent who has been there, done that makes things very difficult from a repeatability point of view.
- "Never" building the same thing twice. In many ways, an airplane is like any other airplane. It's got wings, engines, seats, etc.. Large software projects rarely repeat themselves. Each OS kernel is significantly different. Look at the disparity in file systems. And for that matter, how many truly unique OSs are there? The big ones become clones of a base item at some point. [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX), [Solaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29), [HP-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX), ... herald back to [AT&T System V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V). Windows has had an incredible amount of drag forward through each iteration. Linux variants generally all go back to the same core that Linus started. I bring it up, because the variants tend to propagate faster than the truly unique, proprietary OSs.
- Really bad project estimation. Since the repeatability factor is so low, it's difficult to project how large it will end up being and how long something will take to build. Given that project managers and Management can't put their hands on the code and actually see what is being done, unrealistic expectations regarding timelines get generated.
- QA / QC is not emphasized as heavily as it could or should be for larger projects. This goes back to having looser interfaces between components, and not having rigid specifications for how components should work. That looseness allows for unintended consequences and for bugs to creep in.
- Consistently measurable qualifications. Generally, people speak of the number of years they've worked in X language or in programming. Time in is being used as a substitute for caliber or quality of skill. As has been mentioned many times before, interviewing and finding good programming talent is hard. Part of the problem is that the definition of "good" remains very subjective.

I don't mean to be all negative, and I think the software industry has made significant strides from where we've been. Forums like this and others have really helped promote conversation and discussion of design principles. There are organizations working to standardize on "baseline" knowledge for software engineers. There is certainly room for improvement, but I think the industry has come a long way in a reasonably short period of time.

Comment: It was difficult to pick an answer to accept among several very good answers, but I finally select this one despite the fact that it doesn't have the highest votes. In fact, both this answer and the one by m3th0dman precisely *why* there is such specificity in IT industry, helping to understand *what* to do in the future to close the gap. Compared to the answer by m3th0dman, this one seems much more detailed.

Comment: +1 but might I just add that since software exists in the realm of the mind, it has *almost infinite* possibilities, whereas every plane every built must contend with the finite requirements of reality.

Comment: +1 for "QA / QC is not emphasized as heavily as it could or should be for larger projects." Would you fly in an airplane that was built "quick and dirty"? What about using a bridge that was built "faster" without any "needless" testing to delay things?

Comment: Very well answered.  As an interesting example--imagine if a large plane was designed and implemented by a bunch of people without process or company history--people that just got together and formed a business to build a plane on the scale of a 747 from scratch.  That's how 90% of the software projects I've seen are done.  The other 10% with experienced architects and companies with history and process seem to be a lot more successfull.  For a counter-example look at the development process behind software that causes people to die when it fails.

Comment: @MainMa you should not choose the highest voted answer, but the one that helped you the most.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: I know and I already did it before, but I still find it useful to explain why I disagree with the votes where there is a considerable gap between the highest voted answer and the one I accept.

Comment: I think you accepted the wrong answer. Danny Woods was right, failures in other industries are just as frequent, and programming isn't building it's design. Construction in the software world is done by the compiler and is virtually free. 

Your original question was very telling _Once the preliminary work (design, specifications, etc.) is done on paper_ the design and specification work of a physical structure is an EXACT specification of how to build the structure. The only thing matching that in the software world is code. Code is design, compilation is construction.

Comment: @MikeBrown - I view the high voted answers as complementary.  What I felt MainMa was getting at is why large software **projects** have high failure rates.  My reference to Yourdon is partial evidence to this being a large topic of discussion within software engineering.  Focusing the conversation on design vs. build | compile ignores all the other SDLC aspects within a project.

Comment: But the question itself is flawed. While we do need to turn a critical eye toward our own shortcomings. Acting as if the software industry is the only one that has unsuccessful projects is ludicrous. To say "once all the design has been done" is telling as well. Even if you don't agree that programming is a design activity, how often do you see detailed, iron-clad design done up front for software? People give fuzzy specs on software because they anticipate being able to change the software if the specs weren't right without caring how those changes might impact the entire solution.

Comment: @MikeBrown - I think the question ignores the challenges other industries have faced and sometimes resolved.  And I do agree that other industries have had their own spectacular failures.  For me, the question focused on why software projects had such an abysmal successful completion rate.  Programming is definitely design, but a software project is much more than just programming.  I've worked on projects with tight specs and those with loose specs.  What amount was done upfront depended upon the criticality of the system.

Comment: I wish you had mentioned *why* we never build the same thing twice: because we don't have to.  I would also point out that we rarely hear of huge failures in software products.  They fail early, or succeed as small applications and evolve into successful large applications.

Comment: Add to the list: "Horrible resource and project management as standar"

Answer (score 481):

The answer is surprisingly simple: those 'other industries' *do* have a high failure rate.  We're just comparing the wrong things.  Writing software is often called 'build', and so we compare it to the manufacturing or construction phases in other industries.  But if you look at it, it's not construction at all: it's *design*.  Software designs are written in code, and building is done by computers, whether by compiling software or directly interpreting it on the fly.

Many designs in other industries either take way longer than originally estimated, cost way more, or simply never see completion.  Sound familiar?

So, what are we doing when we're planning software?  Well, we're still designing, but at an earlier stage.

In software, there's no manufacturing line of note.  Building the final component is (comparatively) cheap, and replication of that final product is both perfect and effectively free--you copy the build artifacts.

Comment: Even in the industry the OP mentioned, Aerospace, the Boeing 787 Dreamliner and JSF F-35 have both had significant delays. Last week a carpark collapsed in one of the major shopping centres in Sydney. Sydney has very rigorous building standards but mistakes happen.

Comment: A thousand times this. Even the question's schedule link shows that the project was actually in development from 1988. The source code is the design: http://www.developerdotstar.com/mag/articles/reeves_design.html

Comment: Many large projects like the F-35, Hubble Telescope, etc were late because of the software side of development. The Hubble actually sat in storage for years because the software was not ready.

Comment: @pkh: well seen, Reeves proposed that "code as design" idea 24 years ago!

Comment: @MrLane:In the real world it works like this. A schedule is set for when the hardware is supposed to be done and the software is supposed to be done. The hardware designers provide an ICD to the software team so the sw team can write their code without the hardware. The hardware slips its schedule, by a lot and changes its interfaces to work around the hw issues, frequently without notifying the sw team. Finally, the hw sort of works and is delivered, way late. Of course the sw doesn't work because of the myriad of unexpected hw "features". Because it is cheaper to fix hardware problems in...

Comment: software, the sw team now has to incorporate the changes to the ICD and come up with workarounds for buggy hardware. So in addition to the hw being delivered way late and now the sw team is also fixing buggy hardware, who gets the blame for being late? Well, the software team isn't done yet. It is the software that is late. Everyone always forgets about the electrical, mechanical and systems engineering schedule slips that sw depended upon and then that forced sw to be rewritten and have extra requirements. All they see is that the sw team is still coding. Thus, the software is late.

Answer (score 191):

To point out some figures:

1. **Change of requirements after implementation started**; for example when the first Airbus A380 started to be created in the factory I cannot believe that if someone wanted 200 more seats, those would be put there; but in a large software project even after the programmers started development 5 more types of users can be added.
2. **Complexity** - large software projects are extremely complex; probably the most complex projects human kind designed and developed;
3. Not enough resources are spent in **architecture and design phase**;
4. **Field immaturity** - software engineering is relatively a young discipline compared 
   with other engineering sisters; this has two implications:
   a) Not so many heuristics and good practices;
   b) Not so many very-experienced specialists;
5. **Lack of mathematical proof** - in most of the cases mathematical formal methods are not used to prove that a piece of software works as required; instead testing is used. This does hold true in other engineering fields which rely more heavily on mathematics;  the reason of this is as complexity;
6. **Rush** - many managers have unachievable deadlines; so quality of code is placed second, because of the deadline.

Answering strictly to the question - I tend to believe that others have very high expectations (especially in delivery time) from programmers and do not understand exactly how difficult programming large software is.

Comment: Formal mathematical proof in software, besides the fact that it is often practically impossible to do right, is ultimately nothing more than writing the program twice (once in the actual programming language, and once in the formal-proof specification language) and verifying that both versions do exactly the same.

Comment: I agree upon the fact that formal methods are practically impossible to be applied upon large projects. The difference is that a program described by a formal specification (Z, VDM) is correct due to mathematics; but a program written in a typical programming language needs to be tested.

Comment: tdammers, there are tools that can help you write both at once: Coq supports "program extraction" to extract a program in OCaml or Scheme from a certified Coq program.

Comment: "Change of requirements after implementation started". I call this the "moving the toilet problem".  
  
You are building a house, are putting finishing touches on the bathroom, and the owner wants the toilet in a different place. You give them the cost estimate. They balk, saying "why so much, I just want the toilet 8 feet away?". You then explain that you have to install new plumbing, rip open walls/floors, etc. to be able to move to toilet.  Late changes are always expensive.

Comment: I'd say testing an airplane is actually much more difficult than testing a software. With airplane, all the mathematic magic you conjured ends up useless when you figured that the software simulator or the wind turbines you created doesn't really reflect the way things works when you're up there. Formal proof in software is only a hard problem, compared to formal proof in engineering which is impossible.

Comment: #1 in your list is the most important IMO, i'd add two more things to it: 

-Lots of big changes can be made in a short timeframe (for example 'lets switch the communication protocol!'), that wont break stuff in the short term, but many of these make the project very hard to manage in the long term.

- The changes in the environment where the software runs can change drastically over a short time. While the basic premises for an airplane will stay the same (must fly in storms, must land on solid runways,..), a software can totally break, if the new verison of the OS comes out for example.

Comment: To expand on what sydd said, there's a limit to how much duct tape and bondo you can put on a project before you get shut down and have to start all over. In software, duct tape and bondo are largely invisible even to your fellow engineers unless they deeply inspect your code, and project managers have no idea of what the difference even is compared to good design, so they'll demand more of it to make up time. Big software is often more body shop than mass manufacturing.

Comment: #3 is a good point, I've seen too many projects which start without a (good) software architecture plan. This results in a higher occurrence of unknowns which brings all kinds of problems.

Comment: Most of these are true of physical construction projects as well.

Comment: In 2009 a software OS kernel was mathematically proven to be correct. It took 30 man years to verify 7500 lines of code. DO the math - how long to verify something useful - e.g. Linux -  is bug free, even assuming linear complexity etc it ain't going to happen any time soon.   (refer http://phys.org/news173086905.html)

Comment: @tdammers, writing a program and proving that it is correct is not the same thing. It is possible to write a correct program which will be *impossible* to prove that it is correct.

Comment: @Alexey: What I'm saying is that an automated formal proof of correctness requires a definition of 'correct' behavior in a formal language. But then, defining the behavior of a piece of software in a formal language is exactly what programming *is*.

Comment: The proof does not have to be automated, it can be done "by hand" in plain language, but probably there are some logical systems that are better suited for this. (I have learned recently about Hoare logic, for example.) Defining a behavior is not enough to implement it.  Consider the problem of factorizing a given integer as the product of primes, for example.

Comment: no "Change of requirements after implementation started" LOL - see http://globalprojectstrategy.com/lessons/case.php?id=23 they didn't add seats, but instead a two year delay after manufacturing started due to having to redesign as the requrements for the electrical systems not being copied correctly from one computer to another.

Answer (score 145):

The premise of the question is a bit flawed.  Both the A380 and the Boeing 787 were delivered years late.

In the case of the A380 much of the delay was caused by the French and German units of Airbus using [different and slightly incompatible versions of CATIA](http://www.businessweek.com/stories/2006-10-04/airbus-first-blame-the-software) design software. This incompatibly manifested itself as wiring harnesses that didn't quite fit the airplane.

There wasn't anything wrong with CATIA, which is the most widely used aircraft design software, but someone somewhere dropped the software configuration ball.

The Boeing 787 also suffered from software related delays, but most of its problems were more traditional new airplane problems like weight control and delivery of substandard parts by suppliers.

Both the A380 and the B787 had to modify their wing designs after the initial aircraft had structural issues.

Large complex projects are difficult for humans in all fields.

Comment: Agreed. I think there's a false attitude that software is "produced more sloppily" than physical stuff because bad software ends up with fixes which are very visible, plus everyone has to deal with broken software. If a plane is a piece of crap and they have to do some work on it you don't send it back, it's just something the mechanics complain about amongst themselves in most cases, unless it's a *huge* defect. And those happen too.

Comment: I think the question still stands even though the examples are flawed. It is statistically proven, that software projects have much bigger final costs and take much longer that predicted.

Comment: It should be noted that the design and implementation of a commercial airliner system inherently includes the completion of a massive, and massively complicated, IT project, one that *has* to be fully and correctly functional.

Comment: Highway construction would qualify as large scale projects.  Those are frequently completed on-time or ahead of time.  Building construction is another example of large scale that can complete on-time or ahead of time without that being an exceptional thing.

Comment: And given that the A380 had a major recall as recent as 2010, I wouldn't call it "flawless" even then.

Comment: Also, LOTS of concept airplanes have been funded and canceled over the years, particularly military contracts. Airplanes are not good examples at all, because we don't hear about many of the (classified) failures until many years or decades later.

Comment: Or sometimes we do hear of the failures, and it's heart breaking - like the Lockheed Martin X-33 project.

Comment: Both A380 and Boeing 787 are planes. Planes have large and complex software installed in them that interacts with the things that the "other industries" are building. Who knows, maybe their were years late mainly because of software issues.

Comment: Exhibit A, your Honour: http://avherald.com/h?article=44992a89

Answer (score 116):

Skyscraper guy here. Not sure if I can answer your question but I can surely shed some light into various items in the thread. Buildings do indeed occur very fast. A major constraint is locale (regulations). But in general it takes 3 to 10 years for a tall building from start to finish.

I think comparing a new building with a new software project is not very accurate. A new building is closer to a new version of a kernel or OS. In this respect software development is much faster. We never build from zero as this will be a high risk task the client would never sign up for. Most design and development in buildings is derivative of proven and completed projects.

From personal experience only one in ten projects ever get built. The process is development-driven rather than design-driven, so the moment something like the price of steel goes up the whole project is out the window, or designed, as design is the cheap component of the process.

Design takes a month for concept to schematic, two to six months to design development, another six months to details and construction documents by a team of architects, planning consultants, structural engineers, wind engineers, services engineers, quantity and cost consultants, surveyors, accessibility engineers and the list goes on...

The argument of virtual versus physical is not very accurate. We also work mainly with virtual tools, and moreover we are both time- and scale-remote from our final product. In most cases we can not even test aspects of buildings in mockup scale and we use simulation to try predict what may come about.

Complexity-wise there are differences, but overall it is maybe about the same. We not only have interrelated units and multiple levels of tiered abstractions and interfaces but also people are very much specialized in small parts of the process that make communication very difficult.

As for the argument of design versus development, I think both processes are design-built. It sounds academically nice to keep these separated but it is not possible to design if you don't know how things work. You just increase the risk of failure.

Overall my (potentially wrong) estimation as per OP's question is that programming is more of an art than engineering. Why would people take pleasure and even do it for free, find expression and elegance in it? Computer science is also (as on the tin) more of a science than engineering. Why would you try to prove algorithms instead of just patching existing parts together and work to make things just work? Not sure if this makes any sense; I'm not a software guy.

One aspect that strikes me with software design and development is about the medium itself. Computers make human-centric work very unnatural. Everything is so very explicit and there are few tolerances. It's hard to mentally work your way around this, and some get away with it by dumping complexity within. If nothing else this may have something to do with it?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the insight. "to design if you know know how things work" -> " to design if you don't know how things work" ?

Comment: Hey builder, I suggested some edits to this post, I think you have excellent points, I just tried to clean up some grammar.

Comment: I definitely agree with the point about programming being more of an art than engineering. I often find creativity as a core aspect in software design.

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that a large software project and a tower have similar complexity - based on my experience working as both a structural engineer and a software engineer, I'd say software complexity is much higher. There's probably a raft of reasons for this, but the one I'd suggest is that there's a whole lot of wiggle room in engineering; the upper bound of construction design is almost always given by cost, and that's a soft constraint. Software needs to be *exact*, since computers don't deal with ambiguity well. Slab not working? Add a shitload of steel, she'll be right.

Comment: Some people do [design and build buildings for pleasure.](http://www.sagradafamilia.org/en/) Don't tell my employer, but now that I think of it some of my software is like the *Sagrada Familia:* Idiosyncratic, too many ornaments, never quite finished; but of interesting design, fun to build and use and still standing.

Answer (score 46):

Then how long did the design of those took? Year? Two? Ten years? The design is the most complex part of building something, the construction itself is easy.

Based on [this article](http://user.it.uu.se/~carle/softcraft/notes/Reeve_SourceCodeIsTheDesign.pdf), it is slowly being understood, that software development is mostly design process where design document is the source code itself. And the design process is totally different from the production process. It requires experienced people and is impossible to plan, because even small requirement changes can result in huge changes in the overall architecture of the project. This understanding is the basis for [agile methodologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) that focus on improving code quality as the final design document and taking testing and debugging as parts of the design process, just like they test airplane models in wind tunnels.

The construction itself is handled automatically by compilers. And thanks to that, we are able to build whole products in a matter of minutes.

The reason why software projects are finished with huge delays and inflated costs is because managers still think they can estimate, predict and plan such a design process. This backfires more often than it is actually valid. They still think that by tying people into a rigid construction process they can somehow increase quality even though end result is mostly opposite with increased costs and missed deadlines.

Comment: "This understanding is basis for agile methodologies". Exactly. The waterfall method makes sense for skyscrapers: you want every detail in the blueprint to be right before you pour the foundation. But if tearing down and rebuilding skyscrapers were free and near-instantaneous, like compiling code is, you'd probably use an iterative process.

Comment: @NathanLong: Especially if they came out with new forms of concrete every three years, and somebody figured out how you could run multiple elevators in a single shaft, and suddenly steel wasn't cool anymore and everyone decided to build their frameworks out of carbon fiber.  Stuff like that goes on *all the time* in the software industry.

Comment: "software development is mostly design process where design document is the source code itself" you just opened my eyes. Thanks.

Comment: @TMN Imagine if while building a skyscrapper, they'd change the color palette of the interior because it doesn't look right. That apply for any component of the building. Trying to run multiple elevator on a single shaft is one thing, but you'd have to test 20 elevator from different supplier before even trying to hook all of them to the shaft...

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: *Engineers* might test 20 different elevators, devs would simply use the one described in the blog post where they first heard about it. Then when the building opened and there was a problem with the elevators, they'd discover that the company that built them no longer existed. When they tried to get replacements from a different supplier, they'd discover their original elevators used a non-standard shaft...

Comment: @TMN No, this is an example of bad dev. A bad engineer could also take the cheapest supplier without looking at the detail of what they're using. A good dev on the other hand would take into account the following things before choosing a component. Project alive? Easily maintainable if things need fixes? Well documented? Are there other good alternatives? Is it flexible enough or too complicated? All of the question a dev could ask himself before choosing a component are weight for making a decision.

Answer (score 44):

Imagine, in the middle of the design of the Airbus A380, someone piped up in a meeting and said, "Heh, could build it as a triplane?" Others joined in saying, "Yeah, yeah. A triplane. More wings are better." The next thee years is spent turning the A380 design into a triplane. At another meeting, someone says, "A triplane? That's old. We want a biplane. Just remove one of the wings."

Or imagine, in the middle of a bridge construction project, someone says, "Heh, we just made a deal with a shipping company. They need the bridge to be another 40 feet higher, because their ships are much taller. Fix it. Thanks."

These are but some of the reasons why software projects, big and small, end in failure at an alarming rate.

Comment: This is exactly what happens. The management types or the clients change their mind every 10 seconds which just frustrates the developers. I quit my last job because of crap like this

Comment: This comes to mind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg&feature=kp

Answer (score 22):

As someone with a mechanical engineering background working in IT, I've often wondered about the reasons of the low success rate in IT.

As others in this thread, I've also often attributed the failures to the immaturity of IT, the lack of detailed standards (yes I'm serious, have you ever checked the standard sheet of a simple bolt?) and the lack of standardized components and modules.

Other industries, like building construction or ship building also have much more "beaten paths": knowledge and experience of a particular solution prototype, which - in customized form - is re-used again and again. Ever wondered about why buildings, ships or airplanes of different size and purpose somehow look so similar? (there are exceptions to the rule of course...)

That is because those prototypes are well researched, well understood, generally used and have a proven track record. Not because it couldn't be done any other way. In IT standardization is rarely the case: (large) projects tend to re-invent components, doing research and delivery at the same time *and* with the same people!

These inevitably lead to one-off products, which are expensive to develop and service, are error-prone and fail in unpredictable ways under uncertain conditions. And because of this, of course, these products are much quicker obsolete, written down and replaced at equally great costs with only slightly better ones. What IT needs is the equivalent of the industrial revolution, which turned middle-age artisans into efficient factories.

That said, there are factors that make IT truly unique however. As opposed to those other mentioned industries, IT is truly ubiquitous: it is used in *every* aspect of our modern life. So it's a small miracle IT achieved this much progress and is capable of delivering the results it does.

Comment: +1. Good example for the standardization (standard sheet of a simple bolt). In IT, rare are the components which are normalized. Take registration forms: every website reinvent their own, and few are the developers who know how their registration form behaves with unicode, with empty strings, with strings too long, etc.

Comment: @MainMa: poor example, do you create your buttons, textboxes, option boxes, option boxes from divs? No, you reuse the browser's form elements; and the browsers used the Operating System's form elements.

Comment: I were rather speaking about the internals, not the controls. Take some random website. Can you use Chinese characters for the password? Can you use 25-characters passwords? What will happen if you put a whitespace in password or user name? All this could be normalized, but it's not, and every person is reinventing the wheel for every project, often badly, i.e. no hashing and/or salting, or passwords limited to sixteen characters (example: MSN), etc.

Comment: Changing IT from "artisans" to "factories" may not be possible. Factories are executing a process which has already been created. Workers in a factory execute their process with little or no human thought. Many factories have replaced humans with robots due to this fact. In software you are not executing a process, but creating one. Creating software would be more akin to designing the factory and it's processes rather than running the factory. Although software creation could benefit from standards, it cannot fundamentally become a factory.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko it's a bad comparison to compare "data sheets for bolts" (i.e. tools, equipment) to "registration forms standards". Registration forms would be more like "a roof" or "a front door" (indeed, there are a zillion ways to make those).  What a bolt compares to is more like a processor pipeline behaviour. It's nowhere close to what we need: reliable OS (with _rigorously_ defined characteristics, not "data may hit the disk depending on the mount options used") and ditto development tools (they need to be able to check 90% of the code for standard properties)

Answer (score 16):

I'm afraid that I disagree with your statement.

Airbus and Boeing are two examples of companies that build planes. How many companies that build planes are there? Very few, if you would compare it to how many companies build software.

It is equally easy to screw an airplane project as to screw a software project. If only the entry barrier was so low in the aircraft-building industry as it is in the software industry, you will certainly see many failed aircraft projects.

Look at cars; There are high-quality manufacturers that build very durable and highly advanced automobiles (think Land Rover, Mercedes) and there are ones that build cars that won't last a year without having to repair them (think Kia or Cherry). This is a perfect example of an industry with slightly lower entry barrier, were you start to have weaker players.

Software is no different. You have lots of buggy products, on the other hand, Windows, Office, Linux, Chrome, or Google Search are very high-quality projects that were delivered on time and had similar quality level as an aircraft.

The other point that many people miss is how much maintenance goes into maintaining a car, a tanker or an aircraft that we just take as a fact of life. Every plane has to undergo a technical check-up before every take off. You have to check-up your car every several k miles and do so regular stuff like change oil, change tires.

Software needs that too. If only people spent as much time on diagnostics, prevention or auditing software's state and quality as they do with mechanical/physical products, I would expect way less statements like these. Do you read your application's logs each time before you launch it? Well.. if it was an aircraft you would have to ;-)

Comment: Windows has often not been delivered on time (Longhorn, aka Windows Vista, was originally supposed to ship in 2003). I don't know about Office, but most of the other software projects you mentioned explicitly don't have timelines, or their release schedule is so frequent that they include whatever features are ready in the release, and push everything else off until it's ready.

Comment: This is a better example of high quality software: [420,000 lines and bug free: the software that powered the Space Shuttle](http://www.fastcompany.com/magazine/06/writestuff.html). Mind you, there was enormous costs associated with getting this sort of quality.

Comment: @dodgy_coder, Building a safe aircraft isn't cheap either ;-)

Comment: It took something like a decade for Windows to get to a decent quality state, too.

Comment: @PaulNathan decent is very subjective ;)

Comment: @KarimA.: Building a safe aircraft isn't cheap, but a big part of what makes an aircraft safe, is software... So an important part of the aircraft design is actually software design!

Answer (score 11):

Digital building blocks can be 1 or 0. There is no inbetween.

A mechanical design has a level of tollerance. I can put one less than perfect rivet into a bridge and it will most likely will not fall down, however, in code even just once instance of putting a 0 where a 1 should be can fail the entire program.

Due to the logical and interative nature of computing, any, even very small changes, can lead to drastic failure.

Comment: I once heard someone say "Construction would be just like programming if when you put the final doorknob on the house backwards, the entire house exploded".

Comment: @MorganHerlocker but then you restore the house from source control and try again

Answer (score 9):

I have often wondered the same thing. It certainly *feels* (occassionally) like we're a bunch of amateurs that don't have any idea what we're doing. I dislike explanations that put the blame on managers or other external factors -- we the developers should be responsible for what we create.

I think we are in a business where **errors are cheap**. Patching software is cheap, compared to rebuilding a skyscraper, or recalling every sold cellphone.

This has created a culture where **bugs are a part of everyday life**. They are accepted with a shrug. While some bugs are probably unavoidable, should they [dominate our day to day work](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152464/im-doing-90-maintenance-and-10-development-is-this-normal)? I completely understand managers who don't feel that QA is worth the trouble, precisely because they expect bugs anyway. I don't understand programmers who don't make every effort to produce error-free code, because correcting bugs is boring as hell.

In essence I believe it is a culture problem, and I hope it will change.

Comment: Do you understand programmers who don't make every effort to produce error-free code, because that would take twice as long and management is breathing down their necks to implement these new features *yesterday?*

Comment: Shouldn't that be true of other industries as well? I don't deny that external factors don't exist, but I believe that a change must come from the inside. If software engineers embraced their role as experts in their field, their recommendations and estimates would be respected and not second-guessed by management. Or am I being to naive?

Comment: I am often surprised when I occasionally visit a customer, and watch them use the product i am programming. There are bugs and functionality that makes the way they work very difficult, and as a programmer, I see how  easy that could be made much better for the user, but the user has never complained about it, because he thinks it's not worth the bother to report it.

Answer (score 7):

Engineering standards and practices are very different in IT (as an independent industry) than in [aerospace](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerospace). This is perhaps most easily understood by considering how IT professionals react when encountering standards documents for *IT in aerospace*. For example, the [Joint Strike Fighter C++ Standards](//www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf) that have made their way around the Internet in recent times.

Many express bemusement or wistful resignation (wish we could do that way); and many respond with ridicule, claiming there is no practical way to deliver consumer products in this way. This may even be right, given the expectations, not of consumers, but of management. There is a great deal of distrust for coders who just code and code for a few weeks, not demoing anything. God help the coder who merely *designs* something for two weeks. Not so with airplanes.

In software, people really expect to have something right now. Sure, the reasoning goes, it will take a little while to have it really solid; but can't we have *some complex thing described in simple terms* in a week? One learns, also, that complex things described in honest, complex terms rarely excite the imagination; and thus many engineers end up being complicit in an imagined world of really simple things being put together in creative ways (as opposed to a world of hard things being done really well).

Answer (score 5):

Some stuff from me:

1- Standards and parts: They are plane *manufacturers*, not developers. I am not entirely sure, but my guess is that a lot of parts are outsourced. They don't build their own electronic/instruments, they get seats from some company, the engines are probably developed elsewhere, etc.

Software projects, on the other hand, almost always start from scratch with just some small frameworks/helpers in place.

2- Time to hit the market: Time is not a critical issue for planes. I bet the design of the Airbus was finalized years before it was finished, and they did chose to neglect any major breakthroughs that might happen in that time. (Same for car manufacturers, for example, the cutting-edge technology they develop at the moment will hit the streets in 5-10 years.)

For software you need to be very agile, if I start a huge project now and take three years to develop it without any change the chances are pretty high that I am relying on technology that is not available anymore or my product is completely outdated. This in turn offers a lot of problems.

3- Release-cycle and versions. - A plane needs to be completely finished when it is "released". There are no stable beta versions, nightly builds or similar. Additionally, once it's done, it can only be modified in a small way. You can't add an additional level with 100 seats to an existing boeing, it's just not possible.

Software on the other hand has incremental changes that are often just "builds that work", but not necessarily finished products. Also, in IT it's not unusual to say "hey, let's add another luggage compartment to our plane which holds additional 50 tons".

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is quite simple:

1) Physical construction and implementation have been around for as long as people have - we've had thousands of years to develop our methods and techniques for implementing physical projects. Software 'construction', which requires an entirely new and different skill-set, is no more than 50 years old - we haven't had enough time figure it all out yet.

2) Virtual construction is harder - you have to 'see' things in you mind that have no physical reality whatsoever. It requires you to analyze and abstract a lot of information before you even know what your product is supposed to look like and the steps it will take to create it. Not so when building a bridge or a building.

3) It's often much more difficult to find the source of a software failure or bug than it is when doing physical engineering. If a girder buckles, you see where it's buckling and you see the supports that are holding it and failing, etc. Finding a software defect can entail examining a great deal of code and interacting processes - difficult, time consuming, and not bound to the laws of physics and math in the way that physical structures are.

Answer (score 4):

I will try answering using a verbatim copy of an article from Jack Ganssle's embedded muse. While this says firmware everywhere, just mentally replace it by software.

> **Compared to What?**
>
> Firmware is the most expensive thing in the universe. In his wonderful
>   book "Augustine's Laws," Norman Augustine, former Lockheed Martin CEO,
>   tells a revealing story about a problem encountered by the defense
>   community. A high performance fighter aircraft is a delicate balance
>   of conflicting needs: fuel range vs. performance. Speed vs. weight. It
>   seems that by the late 70s fighters were at about as heavy as they'd
>   ever be. Contractors, always pursuing larger profits, looked in vain
>   for something they could add that cost a lot, but which weighed
>   nothing.
>
> The answer: firmware. Infinite cost, zero mass. Avionics now accounts
>   for more than half of a fighter's cost. That's a chunk of change when
>   you consider the latest American fighter, the F-22, costs a cool third
>   of a billion a pop. Augustine practically chortles with glee when he
>   relates this story.
>
> But why is software so expensive? Tom DeMarco once answered this
>   question with these three words: compared to what? He went on to
>   discuss relatively boring business cases, but that answer has
>   resonated in my mind for years. Compared to what? With software we
>   routinely create product behaviors of unprecedented complexity. Sure,
>   the code's expensive. But never in the history of civilization has
>   anyone built anything so intricate.
>
> Consider the following bubble sort, lifted shamelessly from Wikipedia
>   and not checked for accuracy:
>
> ```
> void bubblesort(int * A, int n){
>
>     for(int i(0); i < n; ++i)
>
>         for(int j(0); j < n - i - 1; ++j)
>
>             if(A[j] > A[j + 1])
>
>                 std::swap(A[j], A[j + 1]);
>
> }
> ```
>
> It's a mere 110 non-space characters, perhaps tossed off in an hour or
>   two. Suppose we didn't have software and had to implement a sort using
>   some other strategy. What would it cost?
>
> A mechanical engineer might boast that his profession built sorters
>   long before computers. Consider IBM's 1949-era model 82 card sorter
>   (http://www.columbia.edu/acis/history/sorter.html) with a throughput
>   of 650 cards per minute, rather less than our code snippet might
>   manage even on a 4 MHz Z80. The model 82, of course, only sorted one
>   column of a card at a time; to completely sort a deck could take
>   dozens of passes.
>
> How long did it take to design and build this beast? Years, no doubt.
>   And its functionality pales compared to our code which is so much
>   faster and which can handle gigantic datasets. But that was 1949. How
>   long would it take to build a bubble sort from electronic components -
>   without FPGAs and VHDL, or a CPU?
>
> In an hour I managed a rough block diagram, one above the chip level
>   (blocks have names like "adder," "16 bit latch" and the like). But the
>   sequencing logic is clearly pretty messy so I've just tossed in a PLD,
>   assuming at some point it wouldn't be too hard to write the
>   appropriate equations. And, yes, perhaps that breaks the
>   no-programmable-logic rule, but to design and debug all that logic
>   using gates in any reasonable amount of time is as unlikely as
>   buck-a-gallon gas.
>
> Assuming 16 bit words and addresses, the circuit will need around a
>   dozen 16 bit latches, adders, and the like. Plus memory. And I have no
>   idea how the unsorted data arrives into the RAM or how the results get
>   exported. Those are unspecified design requirements.  The
>   software-only solution naturally resolves these requirements just by
>   the act of writing the function prototype.
>
> Translating the rough block diagram to a schematic might take a day.
>   Then there's the time to design and produce a PCB, order and load
>   parts (and change the design to deal with the unexpected but
>   inevitable end-of-life issues), and then of course make the circuit
>   work. We could be talking weeks of effort and a lot of money for the
>   board, parts and appropriate test equipment.
>
> All this to replace 7 little lines of code. Few real embedded programs
>   are less than 10,000; many exceed a million. How much hardware and how
>   much engineering would be needed to replace a real, super-sized
>   computer program?
>
> Consider a real program like a spreadsheet. How much circuitry would
>   it take to make one without a processor? It could be the size of a
>   city.
>
> Firmware is the most expensive thing in the universe, but only because
>   of the unimaginable complexity of the problems it solves. But it's
>   vastly cheaper than any alternative. So when your boss irritably asks
>   why the software takes so long, you know what to say.
>   *Compared to what?*

So there! Software/firmware has unparalleled complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Large projects often occur in large organizations. If you've never worked in a large organization, there is one thing that is guaranteed to kill performance and productivity: bureaucracy.

Surprisingly, many people do not know what bureaucracy is (it is often confused with politics), or even if/when they have a bureaucracy problem.

We recently concluded a project to implement smart card authentication. It was originally estimated at three months. It took 15 months. There were not any cost, budget, scope, or technical reasons for the delay. The scope was actually quite narrow - only for accounts with elevated privileges (administrator accounts), about 1,200 total accounts.

Another significant factor is your business partners. This would include vendors. If your partners have a problem that introduces a delay in your project, there aren't many options that will actually fix the delay problem.  They don't work directly for you, and you may not be able to fire that one person at a partner that may be the cause. The partner can be fired, or can be subject to financial penalties or disincentives, but that does not change the fact that the project has incurred a delay. This is precisely what occurred with Boeing when they undertook a mammoth sourcing strategy with the [Boeing 787 Dreamliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner).

Answer (score 3):

I have a shorter version for you:

Whatever is easy to do, or streamlined, we write a program to do it instead of us.

And then fight with the meta-process instead.

It's not that much true, per se, but every day thousands of blogs are set up, instead of writing blog engines. Every workday, thousands of Excel macros are written, instead of writing specially-designed database applications for these.

There are a lot of other factors - some of them mentioned here - but I wanted to add this point to the discussion.

Comment: I agree. Large programs *can* be delivered flawlessly and on schedule, because they've been done a hundred times over 3 decades. For instance, a text editor.

Comment: Not only that, but the way we deliver large programs flawlessly that have been done before, is we just download the old program from its website and make a copy. But for some reason that doesn't count as a successful large software project.

Answer (score 3):

Software engineering and management is fundamentally different than a lot of other engineering areas. The deliverables aren't physical, and the production process *is* the design and development process. Creating another copy of a piece of software has essentially zero marginal cost; all the cost is found in developing the first copy.

Because of the relative youth of software engineering and management as a discipline, there is some misinformation and falsehoods out that are still taken as fact ([see this reference](https://leanpub.com/leprechauns)) which hinders software development and engineering as a whole.

Comment: +1 on the immaturity of Software development. Civil Engineering has had a couple of thousand years to develop it's practices. Aerospace has had a hundred, and is based on other engineering disciplines. Software is still young. It's also normally poorly understood. People can build bridges over streams or make paper planes as kids - the same isn't really true of software.

Answer (score 3):

Not all developers are created equally.  Some are good, others are, well, not.

Try reading other people's code all the time to get a feel of what I'm saying.  Too many extra logic statements can add risk.  These risks can lead to ill behavior or bugs.  Not enough logic statements and now you have null references.  The good programmer understands this and knows when to do what and where.  But no one is perfect.  Things are complex.  Add the poorly thought out work of others and it is easy to see how projects run away.

Answer (score 3):

Lack of accountability... People get sued when an aircraft crashes. The software industry declines any responsibility in any software defect, therefore creating a lack of incentive to create a robust and safe product.

Comment: I've been saying that for a long time. If you got sued when your app crashed, code would be a lot more robust... And there are a lot of companies I'd like sue - take MS for example: how many hours are lost because of all their updates and patches and bugs and revisions that break other stuff. Sue them for those lost hours and quality will increase QUICKLY.

Comment: If that were the case, cost would increase and features would decrease.

Comment: @JimG. The question was about reliability, not feature nor price. Of course having to make more reliable product will introduce more constraints in your design space and other aspects (feature and cost) could suffer.

Comment: So it sounds like you're comfortable with that trade off, but I don't think that most of the world is, hence the current state of things.

Comment: i am not passing judgement of wich trade off would be best... i just explaining the current state of affair...

Comment: And the cost of a Boeing 737 is $50-80 million. You pay each time you get on one-- do you pay each time you open up Office? If I got paid every time somebody used my software damn straight i'd be dedicated to reliability.

Comment: @FlavorScape yet the microsoft make much more than boeing...

Comment: @Jim G: I would prefer to have 1 stable version of a product rather than have 5 crappy ones.

Answer (score 3):

Cathedrals used to take up to 100 years to build.

Some Airbus airplane needs 1 million lines of code to work.

The more time you have been improving something, the more improvement you get, so give the software industry a couple of centuries of trial-error to get better, and we'll see how much it takes a to develop a solid huge project without bugs or flaws.

Comment: Cologne cathedral was started in 1248, and finished in 1880. 632 years.

Answer (score 2):

Most large projects have a high degree of separability of sub-projects, where you can define a small number of design constraints; the whole project will work when those sub-projects each are completed.  If something goes wrong in a sub-project, the whole effort is not thrown into question; you just look for alternate ways to complete the sub-project (e.g. use a different engine).

This is possible but difficult, both practically and as a matter of human nature, in software projects.

In part, other industries have learned the hard way that this sort of separability is a good thing.  For example, if you're going to use Rolls Royce aircraft engines, you do not need to use special Rolls Royce bolts and attachment points that only work with wings with a particular design, and then if you try to switch to Pratt and Whitney, you have to redesign your entire wing from the ground up (which, in turn, requires a complete redesign of the fuselage, which in turn requires you to buy different seats, which in turn requires you to buy a different in-flight entertainment system, which...).  There may be a few linkages--you can't just swap engines without a care--but big projects generally work better when such things are minimized.

I postulate that big software projects designed as a cluster of small software projects with clean interfaces between each other will *not* fail particularly often, as long as the big project is actually solved by the cluster of small projects.  (It is possible to make a mistake in this regard.)

Answer (score 2):

Building software systems is very different from building physical structures. That is, the **implementation** is very much different. While for example building a huge tanker, you do lots of relatively simple (not easy though!) tasks, such as welding parts together by a robot or by hand, tightening all the nuts and bolts, painting, do the decoration by carrying in all the equipment and furniture and such. All of this is very **simple** stuff to do, really.

However, when it comes to software, it gets much more **complex**. For example, how exactly do you implement the secure login and user credential storing part of the product? What libraries and tools can you use? With what libraries and tools are you familiar with? How exactly do you go about writing the hashing + salting function and **how do you ensure it is secure?** You can do this in so many ways that it's impossible to set any actual practical *design patterns* for these kind of things. Yes, the said design patterns *do* exist on a smaller scale as "best practices", but every single software system is very different from the others, and the field advances and changes at so rapid pace that it's essentially impossible to keep up.

When building a house, you don't really run into such problems where you realize that the main supporting walls seem to be inadequate and need to be replaced, requiring you to demolish the progress so far and start from the base by redoing the support walls. You tackle such issues at the **design** phase, because it's relatively simple to predict what kind of support walls your building needs.

That is not the case with software though. You can't really design the whole product as a single entity and then implement it. The software design process is usually iterative, and the goals and requirements change as the product is being implemented and tested. Software development as a whole is an **iterative process** in which things usually change when least expected, and many times such changes impose challenges which require more work, more complexity and unfortunately and ultimately more money, time and hard work to get right.

So, in essence, the reason why it is hard to deliver big projects and estimate project timelines and roadmaps is that software development and especially working design are very *complex* fields. **Complexity is the root problem.**

Comment: +1, and to take the idea further it's a failure to appreciate that complexity by people outside the industry that leads to unrealistic  expectations, irrational policy and off-the-cuff design. The public sector in the UK is a perfect example. For a public building, say, management try to get the design perfect with expert opinion, extensive consultation and watertight project planning before cutting turf. But put the same people in front of a new IT system and you'll see last minute changes to requirements, db schema, UI... "how hard can it be? It's just a bit of typing"

Answer (score 1):

Though it's hardly the only thing that *could* be mentioned, I think one basic thing is worth pointing out. Most products are intended to fit with existing behavior. Even a product that's a radical breakthrough (for example, the car) is generally built to fit with existing behavior, and simply make it a bit simpler/easier/cheaper/whatever to do that. Yes, there's often *some* side effect on existing behavior as well (for example, getting fuel for the car instead of food for the horses), but most of the latter tends to be a fairly minor side effect.

By contrast, almost any software that doesn't change the behavior of the users (for example, let them do their job considerably more easily) is basically guaranteed to be a complete failure from day 1. Worse, large software projects don't just involve the behavior of users on an individual level, but the behavior of large groups -- often the entirety of the organization.

In short, designing the software itself is often the easiest part of the job. The hard part is redesigning peoples' jobs for them. That's difficult to start with; doing it in a way that will not only work, but also be accepted is much more difficult still.

Answer (score 1):

[Airbus A380](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A380) was not a successful project as you have mentioned. I happen to work in a CAD/CAM company, and I was told that it (we had the Airbus prioject too) was delayed by few years, because they were using different version of software in different company. That is, different parts were being designed in different part of the world. And while integrating they came to know that all the design ca'nt be integrated, so they have to redesign it in one version. So looking at it I don't think it was successful. Had it came 2-3 years before, it would have been game changer for Airbus.

Also regarding robust software, you look at any airplane, car (ABS, EPS, climate control, etc.) or space shuttle they have more than 50% software which are running them and belive me they are very robust. It's just that we are more close to software, and there are many more software programs, so we see more errors in them.

Visit: http://www.globalprojectstrategy.com/lessons/case.php?id=23
and see how much successful Airbus A380 was.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "large project" is skewed.

A large project, technically, can be delivered on time, and flawlessly, granted it is something that's been built many, many times over the years.

- A Pac-Man clone.
- A calculator
- A text editor

I'm sure you're thinking..."but those are *small* projects! A text editor is **simple**." I would disagree with you. Computers are outrageously complicated. Just installing and setting up users on an operating system can be difficult at times, and you didn't even *write* the OS, or build the hardware.

The projects you're talking about are *huge* projects, akin to space exploration. How do you know how long it takes to develop inter-galactic travel? What model do we base it on? You have the known knowns, the known unknowns, the unknown knowns, and finally, the unknown unknowns, which happen to come up a lot in software development.

I think the problem is one of expectation. Just because the technology is there doesn't mean using it is going to be successful (or wise to use) for a while. If other industries behaved like the software industries did, we'd have black hole powered vacuum cleaners for sale by the end of the decade. Or some "visionary" would have the resources to build a moon base, and decide that a Starbucks would really "round out" the experience for visitors. I don't think the problem is the software industry, but the expectations placed *on* it.

Comment: Black hole powered vacuum cleaners? What about functional safety?

Comment: Lack of functional safety? It's a feature! We advocate the use of immutable structures when attempting to clean something with the black hole vacuum cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Software engineer here, with an engineering background, and a wife who works in construction. We've had long discussions (and arguments) on the differences of our jobs.

**Software engineering is about designing new things**. Almost everything basic has been done in an open source library somewhere. In almost any job where a software engineer is hired, she has to design something that doesn't exist.

In something like construction and most forms of engineering, things that would otherwise be in a 'library' in software are already fully designed. Want to build a tower? Just copy and paste the plans from an existing structure, with a few modifications.

In fact, one of the main reasons I decided not to become an engineer is that you spend most of your time designing a 10% improvement to an existing invention, when that same time could be used to program something more visible, like a social network.

There are not many new designs in engineering; an extremely skilled engineer is someone who can manipulate an existing design into something new or improve on it. But almost every programmer is expected to modify designs, hack them, or create something new.

Look back at how far the standards have changed completely, from [assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) to C to C++ to Java, JavaScript, C#, PHP, and so on. There's not a lot of code that can be recycled from 10 or 20 years ago. This is very different to say... the automotive or aeronautics industry when you can keep improving on designs from decades back.

**Project management is notoriously difficult in software**. Time estimates are best done *by people doing the work*, but when they're busy making estimates, *they're not writing code*. This tempts people to avoid any project management at all.

Often, a lot of code depends on specific people, and if these people are late or unable to perform, the code does not move ahead. In contrast, if you wanted to build a car, you can simply hire different people to assemble the tires, the chassis, the battery, the engine, and so on. Object oriented and existing frameworks makes this possible, but it may not be practical when you're designing everything from scratch.

**Failures may be allowed in software**. Testing can be costly. In software, it's very tempting to skip all that testing, when you can just fix a crash. In most forms of engineering, a 'crash' can be fatal.

You do have programming methods that use extensive testing, like [extreme programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_programming) (which was actually used on software megaprojects). But with tight deadlines (that can be made tighter on purpose), it's tempting to skip all that programming and launch with bugs. The [Joel Spolsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) style of "always fixing all bugs" will save more time in the long run, but the undisciplined will skip this and fail.

**Small projects are better**. My wife once asked me to get a job in a big company. It ended up in an argument that big companies are bad companies... to her, a big company had a lot of resources, experience, functional project management, and the right procedures. To me, a big company is a dinosaur, where most of your time is spent on fixing code, testing it, and documentation.

I've seen million-dollar IT projects worked on by less than 10 people. More people would have slowed down the project and added unnecessary bureaucracy. [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp) is an example of a 'small' project that's worth billions of dollars. It's not that big projects aren't possible, but you simply don't need thousands of people to produce billions of dollars worth in software.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in my opinion is the level of abstraction used. Each level of abstraction makes it harder to estimate the exact amount of time needed to complete a certain task.

Whereas a typical Airbus project is mainly using mostly already existing tools (well ok, maybe some tool occasionally isn't up to the task and needs modifications by the tool manufacturer), and creating a plan for how to use those tools to manufacture the particular model (which usually isn't all that different from the already existing models), with software projects this design of next generation Airbus would be mainly to write your `main()` function. That's not all the software engineer does.

Maybe an Airbus requires parallel development at different companies: for example the engine is not built in-house but rather in a separate company. However, in software engineering there's the problem that marginal costs of software are zero, so paying for something you need is almost always a bad choice (with some rare exceptions). Therefore, more of software tends to be built in house and for the rest standard open-source projects may be a good enough solution. In some cases, it may be found that commercially available tools are better than open source tools, but there's a limitation that due to difficulty in funding open source activities, a lot of what you might want may not exist -- and then you need to create it yourself.

With software, you often have to write entirely new libraries. In some cases, you may be able to find an existing library as open-source, but do you trust it more than you would trust a library written yourself? Do you save time or lose time -- if the existing library doesn't work well, you may even lose time to debugging. Is the existing library so intuitive that the 10-100 people who later have to read your code using that library immediately understand what it does?

Actually, using existing libraries is less predictable: whereas you can usually predict the amount of time it takes to write a new library (and the realization may be from anywhere between 0.5 to 2 times that prediction), with an existing library the realization could be between 0.001 to 5 times that prediction (with the worst case being you ditching that existing library and rewriting the damn thing yourself, and the best case being finding out the existing library is marvelously good). So, existing code actually doesn't decrease unpredictability, it increases unpredictability but on the average saves costs, so that's why it's the chosen approach very often.

Not only that, but the level of abstraction is usually higher. You sometimes build libraries -- in traditional engineering, that would be like designing your own power tools. But you don't do only that, you build libraries using libraries -- in traditional engineering, that would be like building robots that use the power tools you just designed. In fact, software engineering very often is more like building robots that assemble more complex robots that use the power tools you have designed. The level of abstraction is just staggering. Just take a typical stack trace that maybe shows 20 entries, maybe 50. In traditional engineering, having 20 stack trace entries would mean you have a tool used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot used by a robot. And 20 stack trace entries isn't even much in the software engineering world.

Sometimes, it has been said that software engineering will be automated away.

But who will build the automation tools then? That's the software engineer.

In fact, I would claim that this automation has made software engineering more productive. Every software engineer is all the time thinking about automating his own job and whether it saves any time -- the best person to automate a task is the person doing that task, assuming that person is capable enough as a software engineer. Unfortunately, this automation will increase the level of abstraction, so while it may save time on the average (assuming the software engineer making decisions has good judgement), but it also increases time schedule risks. Anything making the system more complex, while it may save time on the average, also increases time risks.

Also, sometimes traditional engineering projects get delayed. For example, Olkiluoto-3 nuclear power plant was supposed to be ready in 2009. The last time it was delayed was in 2022, and the latest schedule is after Christmas 2022 it should be running continuously. I think actually that Olkiluoto 3 has more in common with software projects (a huge unique project, a lot built for just this project), rather than with building airplanes. In fact, they are going to build nuclear reactors like airplanes, using manufacturing lines and building standardized designs, and making the things smaller so passive safety can be realized and less complex safety systems are needed. I wish it was that easy for software, too.

Answer (score 0):

For me the main problem that software engineering face is use cases, user and cross platforms.

**Use cases**

How many use cases does an airplane have? Most of it is just to fly from one place to other. Maybe there are more such as radar, traffic control, etc., but the use case is clear and not much. In software engineering, we are faced with unclear requirements and user who do not know what they want. Different user need different configuration / flow, can an airplane be customized as user want (I want to have tv and refrigerator!)?

**User**

Who operates an airplane? A pilot, a copilot, some stewards (if counted) and tower operators. They are all pros and has their job descriptions clear. Software are used by noobs and dummies, not to mention evil hackers and crackers, while still need to be integrateable with other modules (such as [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) or [Google AdSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdSense)). If an airplane can be operated by dummies while still surviving from missiles or ninja robbers, then you can say that the airplane has the same quality with software.

**Cross platforms**

An airplane fly only in the earth's sky. I'm unsure about how they handle the foggy or windy or hot, cold and humid climate, but an airplane is not designed to fly at different gravitation level (I will be amazed if it can fly to [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars)). Sometimes, an application must survive different platforms, such as Internet Explorer, [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) and [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) for browser (sorry [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29)), or Windows XP / 7 / 8, or Linux for OS level. Not to mention mobile devices and different resolution and orientations.

Comment: It always depend on how you define "success".

- try to build a freeway that can be scaled up from 2 lanes to 40 lanes and back down, as the traffic changes, with just a configuration change or even without.
- try to build a plane that is able to accommodate 10.000 passengers, 20 floors and with a configuration change try to scale it down to one floor and 10 passengers, with the fuel consumption decreased drastically.
- implement a feature in aeronautics where you can "back up" the clients and "recover" them in case of a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

One reason which hasn't really been covered in the other questions is that the field of software innovates at a speed which occurs only rarely in the material-based world.

One reason for this is that software evolution is a positive feedback cycle because software (programming languages, build tools, IDEs) is used to build software. It's the most obvious example for Ray Kurzweil's [*law of accelerating returns,*](http://www.kurzweilai.net/the-law-of-accelerating-returns) resulting in progress at exponentially growing speed. Once you have mastered one framework, programming language, communication protocol it's [time to move on](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/09/introducing-stack-overflow-trends/) to the next.

If airplanes were built like software we'd be changing the material with every other model, double their capacity and speed every 18 months, replace the engine technology for each new model with something just invented, while adding the ability to swim and search for extraterrestrial life.

Oh, and ideally it listens to voice commands and doubles as a fully immersive movie theater, paintball arena and night club with dark room once your work trip is over. *The same thing!* (The company which built airplanes which just got you reliably from A to B went belly-up a year after the one with the movie theater, paintball and nightclub feature came out.)

Comment: I don't understand your point. First, many languages are pretty old.  Java is more than twenty years old. Python is nearly thirty years old. Yes, there are new languages, but it's not like we all abandon a language to move to a new one every two years. While adopting new framework, IDE or language may be a factor of slowness for a team, I don't find the ones which use familiar tools particularly fast either. And aircraft industry? Planes like Boeing 787 have *lots* of new things which were challenging to implement.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko Well, Java was hot for web *client* programming after it came out and for GUI building when swing came out but both fads lasted only for a few years. Heck, there was no WWW before the 1990s. Web programming is where airplanes were in 1910 or so. But this pace is *ongoing.*

Answer (score -1):

If you think other industries complete projects without incident you should read the story about the Citigroup Center building built in 1977. Even after nearly 7 years of planning and construction, the building was completed with a serious design flaw that would have caused a collapse from a storm event expected every 16 years.

> In other words, for every year Citicorp Center was standing, there was about a 1-in-16 chance that it would collapse.

The original designers were unaware of the issues, but luckily it was caught by a student studying the building.

> everything seemed just fine—until, as LeMessurier tells it, he got a phone call. According to LeMessurier, in 1978 an undergraduate architecture student contacted him with a bold claim about LeMessurier’s building: that Citicorp Center could blow over in the wind.

Repairs were made literally in the cover of night involving the least amount of people to maintain the secrecy of the design flaw.

An emergency evacuation plan was prepared for the 10-block radius surrounding the building.

> They welded throughout the night and quit at daybreak, just as the building occupants returned to work.
>
> The story remained a secret until writer Joe Morgenstern overheard it being told at a party, and interviewed LeMessurier. Morgenstern broke the story in The New Yorker in 1995.

Which raises the question; how many other fatal design flaws in projects were secretly repaired or ignored without public acknowledgement.

- [The Design Flaw That Almost Wiped Out an NYC Skyscraper (slate.com)](http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_eye/2014/04/17/the_citicorp_tower_design_flaw_that_could_have_wiped_out_the_skyscraper.html)
- [Citigroup Center (wikipedia.com)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citigroup_Center)